# Solr DisMax query equivalent

Tags: solr, dismax

I am trying to set up elevate handler in SOLR 3.5.0 and I need the equivalent of the below query in dismax format which defines different boost values on the same field based on the match type(exact match gets 200 whereas wildcard match gets 100).

q=name:(foo*^100.0 OR foo^200.0)

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to solve this problem.

Keep a text field with only WhiteSpaceTokenizer (and maybe LowerCaseFilter depending on your case-sensitivity needs). Use this field for the exact match. Let's call this field `name_ws`.

Instead of using a wild-card query on `name_ws`, use a text-type [copy field](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields) with [EdgeNGramTokenizer](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory) in your analyzer chain, which will output tokens like:

`food -> f, fo, foo, food`

Let's call this field `name_edge`.

Then you can issue this dismax query:

`q=foo&defType=dismax&qf=name_ws^200+name_edge^100`

(Add `debugQuery=on` to verify if the scoring works the way you want.)